# How to install Gnome in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: gnome, desktop-environments

Is there a way to install Gnome on trusty tahr?

Comment: Thats it? No adding repositories?

Comment: The default repositories will give you Gnome 3.10. The ppa:ricotz/testing mentioned below will give you Gnome 3.12. There are significant differences.

Comment: I am also getting E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine that the OP meant he want have the Gnome Desktop environment on his or her Ubuntu 14.04.

There are two possible answers here:

1. Use the version distributed by Ubuntu Gnome 14.04, which is the Gnome 3.10 version. This is recommended as it does not need to add PPAs.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
   ```

   which should work out of the box. This will install the `gnome-shell` and a series of default applications for the Gnome Desktop experience. You can install just `gnome-shell` if you want, but be warned that this would be an untested (and unsupported) configuration - the desktop configuration is made assuming the presence of the default apps(1).

   This will install a package called `gdm` too, which is the "Display Manager" (the program that shows you the login screen --- and that will setup the basic graphic environment), and will ask you if you want to use `gdm` or `lightdm` (the original Display Manager of Unity). In principle you can choose one of them; in practice sometimes the Gnome Desktop misbehaves if you do not use `gdm`.
2. Use the new [Gnome 3.12, with the PPA](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/05/how-to-install-gnome-312-in-ubuntu.html).  These are experimental packages, you can break your system, and you are supposed to do that only if you are confident you can manage the breakage (as clearly stated in https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3-staging)

> ```
> === *WARNING* ===
> The packages here have been deemed not ready for general use, 
> they have known bugs and/or regressions, sometimes of a critical nature.
> Mostly things should run smoothly but be prepared to use ppa-purge,
> when you encounter issues!
>
> If they break your system, you get to keep both halves.
> ```

---

*Footnotes:*

(1) consider that this is normally not a problem. Linux application for one desktop will generally run on all the others --- I have Ubuntu Gnome with Thunar File Manager (from Xubuntu) and digiKam (from Kubuntu) photo manipulation program, and the only problem is that the "graphical appearance" could be a bit inconsistent... which I really don't care.

Comment: I just wanted to have GNOME DE not Ubuntu Gnome Desktop.

Comment: And if i add Ubuntu Gnome Desktop, will I end with two set of apps?

Comment: And tring to install Gnome desktop from the above method gives the following error: E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: You will have the *union* of the two sets of applications (some are the same). About the error: you have to solve that first --- otherwise nothing will work. Search google for "site:askubuntu.com you have held broken packages". Probably you'll need to purge the PPAs, if you have set them. Sometime to get rid of a broken PPA you need to disable the PPA(s), fix with `apt-get install -f`, re-enable the PPA(s), and then purge. (This is the meaning of "you get to keep both halves" over there...)

Comment: I tried apt-get install -f. Not working.

Comment: What do "not working" means? The PC switched off? Exploded? Please: this is another question, not related to installing gnome. So: 1. Read the links google gives you; 2. try the solutions; 3. if still do not work, add a question stated exactly what you tried and what is the result (what the terminal says when you say it's "failing"). Requires a lot of work on your side, I know, but this is the idea behind SE...

Comment: Not working means not installing out not showing up. I saw a lot of links on google but gnome is not working. Gnome classic, cinnamon, and xfce have been installed by me and they are working

Comment: I give up, sorry. Without further information (point 2 and 3 in my comment above) I would need psychic power to understand what's going on. I hope some user more skilled than me can help you!

Comment: If it involves making a new question, can you help me here?

Comment: This is a volunteer board, where the people asking question are supposed to do their part. If the question is well written, detailed, and complete (see my points 1,2,3 above) someone (maybe including myself, if I can) will surely will be able to help you.

Comment: Just a suggestion, can some one join askers on apps like chrome remote desktop?

Comment: That's up to each one of the people here. Remember, no one is paid for writing here. The idea behind this forum is to let trace of useful answers to help others in the future, so one-to-one solutions like that are, IMHO, not in topic. It is more the kind of thing a paid support service can do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14616/discussion-between-user279288-and-rmano).

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>and run following command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"    
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ricotz/testing 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

Comment: Tried that. Its not working.

Comment: It has been tried. I saw that from a website. Does not seem to work for me.

Comment: @user279288 and by `not working` you mean?... what errors you see?

Comment: It does not appear in sessions after logging out

Comment: @user279288 you use lightdm or gdm? did you switch to gnome from the login screen?

Comment: I dont know what is lightdm or gdm. I am new to Linux.

Comment: Pandya, these are experimental packages. Maybe the OP will be best served by running the standard Ubuntu Gnome version --- not the bleeding edge.

Comment: it is'nt working for me too and i too has the same problem